# How to avoid invoking the Popup Menu of a control when Shift+Ctrl-double-clicking it?

Tags: delphi, double-click, popupmenu, delphi-11-alexandria

In a Delphi 11 VCL Application with a `TPanel` control in Windows 10, the `PopupMenu` property of the Panel has a `TPopupMenu` assigned. When DOUBLE-CLICKING the Panel control at run-time while pressing the SHIFT+CONTROL keys, the POPUPMENU of the Panel is invoked! How can I avoid invoking the Popup menu in this case and execute my own action instead?

```
procedure TForm1.PanelDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0) and (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0) then
  begin
    // Does not work - the PopupMenu is always invoked:
    ShowMessage('The SHIFT+CONTROL keys are being pressed.');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Could set PopupMenu's AutoPopup property to false and manually open it when necessary.

Comment: This shouldn't happen and it doesn't happen on my system (Delphi 10.4, Windows 7).

Comment: @Brian Thanks for a good idea - but unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: Does this happen in a brand new VCL app on your system?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I can confirm that it happens on my system in a brand-new VCL App in Delphi 11.2. (Windows is running in a Parallels VM)

Comment: What happens if you Shift+Ctrl-double-click the Notepad editor? Do you get a context menu then as well?

Comment: If I Shift+Ctrl-double-click the Notepad editor, then also the context menu is invoked.

Comment: @user1580348: Then the problem is your system, likely virtualization (Parallels VM). If you run your VCL app on a "real" system, you won't have this problem. And, conversely, this problem happens in all apps on your system, not only your VCL app.

Comment: Couldn't it be that this behavior isn't happening in Windows 7, and it happens in Windows 10 by default?

Comment: Note that there is right click via CTRL+click in Parallels Desktop. It sends right click into the VM. Usually for Parallels Desktop for Macs as they don't have an actual RMB.

Comment: @user1580348: Extremely unlikely. The Windows desktop has been very stable since the 90s. This is a Parallels desktop thing. (And if Windows 10 treated Ctrl+Shift+double-click like RMB-click or ctx menu I'd discovered that years ago!)

Comment: Looks like newer versions of Parallels use  ctrl+shift+click to simulate RMB as too many Windows programs use ctrl+click.

Comment: The context menu is also invoked with Shift+Ctrl-LeftClick (no double-click), but not with my VCL app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parallels desktop has an alternate way to right click to support a single button mouse. The running VM will only see the right click when this is used.

So your Windows VM is currently receiving two right clicks which it passes on to your Delphi VCL Application.

Ref: https://kb.parallels.com/en/9151

[image]

Comment: You are right: This is the setting in my Parallels version 18.1.0 (53311): https://app.screencast.com/9g83ww1FAW9sf The checkbox "Sekundärklick" must be disabled. Now it works - thank you!

Comment: @user1580348 Using a remote desktop client ("Parallels Desktop") is a key detail that should have been mentioned, much like other environment details that nobody can guess.