# Convert UNC Path to its corresponding mapped Drive path?

Tags: delphi, networking, delphi-11-alexandria

On my test system (Windows 10 x64), the UNC PATH `\\Mac\Home\Documents` is mapped to `Y:\Documents`. Is there a Delphi function to generally convert a UNC Path to its corresponding mapped Drive path (if it has one)?

```
function ConvertUNCPathToDrivePath(const AUncPath: string): string;
```

This would convert `\\Mac\Home\Documents` to `Y:\Documents`.

Comment: I guess you have to get a list/enum of your users net shares and check if the UNC is part of one of those, like with windows cmd "net use"

Comment: I've inspected the Registry, but there are no mappings: https://app.screencast.com/FCne4K1puPZRJ I'm the only user on this test system (Windows 10 x64).

Comment: Such a function cannot exist, because a network share/UNC path does not need to be mapped to a drive or path. Or can be mapped to more than one of any. What is your actual problem you try to solve?

Comment: @AmigoJack Your argumentation is wrong: I did not claim that every UNC path has to have a mapped drive path. You need to UNDERSTAND what you read - not just read the letters.

Comment: I did. Your addition "_(if it has one)_" came many hours after my comment. If you formulate it as 1:1 but mean otherwise it's you who needs to improve. [Or why would my comment get 4 upvotes? Because I "_need to UNDERSTAND_"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74785778/#comment131987668_74786936)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there are no functions to convert a UNC path to a mapped-drive path.

However, there are Win32 API functions, such as [`WNetGetConnection()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetgetconnectionw) and [`WNetGetUniversalName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetgetuniversalnamew), which can be used to convert a mapped-drive path to its UNC path.

You can enumerate the local drive letters and see if any of them convert to the UNC you are interested in.